# How do I pause and restart VirtualBox virtual machines on ACPI suspend?

Tags: virtualbox, suspend, acpi

I use VirtualBox to set up Web developer environments on my laptop. If I suspend the computer and then restart, I'll get very long startup times while VirtualBox spins back up. I have much less of a problem if I pause the virtual machine first.

I'd like to automatically pause the machines on suspend, and start them again on restore. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

what is your host and guest? the pause of guest when the host sleeps usually should be automatic without you having to do anything, but this does not always work and you might have to trap the event in the guest and pause it yourself, when it does not work automatically. search for something like "acpi suspend" for your particular OS might find more information to help you.